# PFQuery objects NOT in a specific PFRelation with currentUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am creating a simple iOS game using Parse for my backend.  PFObjects called "GameObjects" are associated with currentUser through a PFRelation named "gameRelation".  I would like to display a list of games the currentUser could join but has not yet joined.  Is there a way to query  all GameObjects NOT in a gameRelation with currentUser?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to query a relationship through parse but in queries without I have used the notequalto:  .

```
[query whereKey:@"something" notEqualTo:@"something"];
```